# Set only maximum height for a panel (without using setMaximumSize) with GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout, grouplayout

I looked around at all the other answers, but they all recommend to use `GroupLayout`, `BoxLayout`, or to wrap the panel that's using GridBagLayout with another panel that uses one of the layouts mentioned above.

I'm currently using GridBagLayout, and I'm wondering if there's a way to set the maximum height of a panel. I don't want a limit on width, only height, so `setMaximumSize(Dimension)` won't work.

Does GridBagLayout support this in any way? Sorry if my question doesn't contain any code, the only attempt I could possibly find is `setMaximumSize(Dimension)`, or wrapping it in another panel (which I'm hoping to avoid)

Comment: Remember, sizing hints are just that, hints.  Layout managers can ignore them...

Answer (score 10):

If you want to limit only one dimension then just do not limit the other:

```
    component.setMaximumSize( new Dimension(
            Integer.MAX_VALUE,
            requiredMaxHeight
    ) );
```

Comment: This... this is actually a great solution!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would say that almost always the right solution is to fix the layouting either by using a different layout manager, or by using a different hierarchy of containers (or both).

However, since it seems you won't be persuaded (I infer that from your question), I can suggest a solution to the specific question you ask (again, I would recommend to take a different path of fixing the layout, which probably is your real problem).

You can set the maximum height without affecting the maximum width, by overriding the `setMaximumSize()` method as follows:

```
@Override
public void setMaximumSize(Dimension size) {
    Dimension currMaxSize = getMaximumSize();
    super.setMaximumSize(currMaxSize.width, size.height);
}
```

Another approach can be to keep the "overridden" setting of the max height, and return it when returning the maximum height, like so:

```
private int overriddenMaximumHeight = -1;

public void setMaximumHeight(int height) {
    overriddenMaximumHeight = height;
}

@Override
public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
    Dimension size = super.getMaximumSize();

    int height = (overriddenMaximumHeight >=0) ? overriddenMaximumHeight : size.height;

    return new Dimension(size.width, height);
}
```

Again (lastly), I would recommend taking a more common approach, but if you insist ...